# Docker desktop runs in background after launched, but its GUI does not show up, and docker daemon does not run

Tags: docker

Docker icon tray is not appeared too

I have WSL2, Container, Virtualization turned on

My Os: Window 11 version 22H2 build 22616.1

My log file: https://hackmd.io/@kPimGJJTRNKNctJLOvJ3_A/S1yajuLUc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.